# Executing shellcode segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

I've compiled a basic exploit (basically, the source in C doesn't exploit nothing, simply execute the opcodes which execute Bash). The problem is when I execute the binary: "Segmentation fault".

Here what I've done:

**executeBash.asm (NASM)**

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
xor EAX, EAX           ; EAX = 0
push EAX               ; "\0\0\0\0"
push DWORD 0x68732F2F  ; "//sh"
push DWORD 0x6E69622F  ; "/bin"
mov EBX, ESP           ; arg1 = "/bin//sh\0"
push EAX     ; NULL -> args[1]
push EBX     ; "/bin//sh\0" -> args[0]
mov ECX, ESP ; arg2 = args[]
mov AL, 0X0B ; syscall 11
int 0x80     ; excve("/bin//sh", args["/bin//sh", NULL], NULL)
```

**In the terminal:**

```
prompt$ nasm -f elf32 executeBash.asm
prompt$ ld -m elf_i386 executeBash.o -o executeBash
prompt$ objdump -M intel,i386 -d executeBash

executeBash:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8048062:   50                      push   eax
 8048063:   68 2f 2f 73 68          push   0x68732f2f
 8048068:   68 2f 62 69 6e          push   0x6e69622f
 804806d:   89 e3                   mov    ebx,esp
 804806f:   50                      push   eax
 8048070:   53                      push   ebx
 8048071:   89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp
 8048073:   b0 0b                   mov    al,0xb
 8048075:   cd 80                   int    0x80
prompt$ # "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
prompt$ ./executeBash
$ exit
prompt$
```

The exploit in ASM runs perfectly.

**exploitBash.c**

```
void main()
{
    char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
                       "\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
    void(*fp) (void);
    fp = (void *)&shellcode;
    fp();
}


prompt$ gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack exploitBash.c -o exploitBash
prompt$ ./exploitBash
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: So, you are complaining that _undefined behaviour_ behaves undefined?

Comment: @RossRidge amm, it's truth... What's the problem, then?

Comment: @RossRidge I edited the line because you said my code isn't in the stack. It's edited now with the latest parameters. Segmentation fault.

Comment: It's working for me. (with `-z execstack`; I'm also passing -nostdlib because my gcc32 setup is messed up and this doesn't need stdlib).

Comment: @PSKocik It's strange... I'm using the latest version of Kali, and the ASM source works, but the C source no...

Comment: Might be overly security-conscious system settings on Kali. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70828159/exploitBash is what I got with `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack exploitBash.c -nostdlib -o explitBash`, you can `cmp` it and if they're the same, it's your system that's preventing it. (I used gcc 4.9.2 -- that might make a difference too).

Comment: `shellcode` might be mappend into a page that is marked as “do not execute.” Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that what you want to reference is `&shellcode` and not `shellcode`?  After all, shellcode is already a pointer... you're just casting it to be a function pointer rather than a char pointer.

Comment: @PSkocik With -nostdlib, the exploit works. What's the problem?

Comment: It's working with even with stdlib included (i.e., with no -nostdlib).

Comment: @FUZxxl But I specify the stack isn't executable with the compilation.

Comment: @PSkocik For me, without -nostdlib no.....

Comment: @DavidHoelzer for an array: `shellcode == &shellcode == &shellcode[0]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to set up `edx` so it contains whatever the C code last used it for and that's unlikely to be a valid environment pointer. In the standalone code, `edx` happened to be zero due to the initial startup state of the program. If you use `strace` you can see that the `execve` returns with `-EFAULT` and then execution continues past your code into garbage which then truely segfaults. You can fix the shellcode for example like this:

```
char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69"
               "\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\x31\xd2\xcd\x80";
```

(I included a `xor edx, edx` before the `int 0x80`.)

Comment: Perfect. But what is EDX for excve()? In another words, why must be zero for the excve() execution?

Comment: `edx` is the 3rd argument, the pointer to the environment variables. It may also be `NULL`. See [man execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).